# Highcharts xrange chart is not respecting datetime xAxis min and max values - shows space on both sides

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

How can I get my chart to respect the min and max xAxis values I have set without padding the chart on both the left and right? I basically want to start the chart on the far left at the min xAxis value and have it end at the far right at the max xAxis value without any extra padding/margins on either side.

Here are the chart options I'm using:

```
{
  "title": {
    "text": "Zone History"
  },
  "chart": {
    "type": "xrange",
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "datetime",
    "min": 1500678032000,
    "max": 1500684162000,
    "startOnTick": false,
    "tickmarkplacement":"on",
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": "",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 0,
    "labels": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "tooltip": {},
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "grouping": false
    }
  },
  "noData": {
    "style": {
      "fontSize": "24px",
      "color": "#202030"
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "Zone 5",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": 1500677781000,
          "x2": 1500678032000,
          "y": 0
        }
      ],
      "_colorIndex": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Zone 6",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": 1500678104000,
          "x2": 1500679562000,
          "y": 0
        },
        {
          "x": 1500682921000,
          "x2": 1500684162000,
          "y": 0
        }
      ],
      "_colorIndex": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Zone 7",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": 1500679583000,
          "x2": 1500680765000,
          "y": 0
        }
      ],
      "_colorIndex": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Please see the included fiddle for the current version of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/evgcbtrj/

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting pointPlacement to 'on' should help you to get rid of the unnecessary padding on both sides of the chart.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
     pointPlacement: 'on'
  }
}
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointPlacement

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nnt5t1ho/